# Polite way to ask someone to delete an official email I sent to them by mistake

Tags: professionalism, communication, email

I sent an email to a customer containing sensitive company information.

Unfortunately, in CC, I added another person from another organization who is not supposed to receive the email.

How can I ask him formally and politely to delete the received email?

Comment: Have you consulted your supervisor or manager on this?

Comment: Yes sure, he asked me to send an email to the person asking him to delete the email. I want a professional email to mask a bit the unprofessional dead haha

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How can I ask him formally and politely to delete the received email?

You can reply to the email keeping only the unintended recipient as the receiver and convey your request in a formal and polite tone.

> Dear Sir/Madam,
>
> The email last sent to you in this thread contains sensitive company information which is not intended to be received by anyone other than the original recipient. It was sent to you in accident by me. I sincerely apologise for the same and any inconvenience it may have caused.
>
> I kindly request you to delete the email from your mailbox and obliterate any copies made of the same in any form (whether digital, physical).
>
> Thank you
>
> *Signed*

Comment: Adding to this, be sure to inform anyone who needs to know of your mistake for the purposes of transparency, so it does not appear you are attempting to hide your mistake.

Comment: You could also ask them to confirm that they have done as requested, or rephrase as a question inviting a response. 'Would you be so kind as to ...'